# Why is face-recognition module not found, but requirement already satisfied for cmake, dlib and face-recognition

Tags: python, face-recognition

I am trying to use the python face-recognition module, but it is not working.I have pip installed cmake, dlib and face-recognition but it is still not working, and when i try to add it to the pycharm modules, it says error, i think it is my dlib error, even though it is pip installed, it isn't being found by my pycharm, i have tried installing all versions of dlib, with no outcome. i am really desperate to get the module to work, can anyone help me

Comment: Show us the error.  Be sure to tell us WHICH package you are trying to install, and how you installed it.

Comment: It is a possibility that you have not configured your python environment properly in Pycharm. Try to run the same script from command line.

Comment: Can you paste the exact error message that you get. Did you install them in a virtual environment in Pycharm or in a system environment?

Comment: Check if face_recognition_models being installed too. Normally it should be installed by face_recognition by itself but you'd better check it. Also check if dlib has been really istalled: on Windows pip dosn't intall it from whl but compiles it on-place.